# MySQL Adding conditional logic and Combining SELECT

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I want to simplify my code by moving the selection logic away from Java and into MySQL and also would like to simplify the two queries into a single one.

I have two tables `marriage_data` with columns `player_id_1` and `player_id_2`
Then I have `player_data` with columns `player_id` and `username`

Given an integer from the method, I want to search `marriage_data` in columns `player_id_1` and `player_id_2` for a match

If I find a match at `player_id_1`, I want to get `player_id_2`
If I find a match at `player_id_2`, I want to get `player_id_1`

With the id retrieved, I want to select `username` from `player_data` where the retrieved id is equal to `player_id`

Currently I am using this code to get my desired result:

```
private String getSpouse(Connection conn, int id) throws SQLException {
    try (PreparedStatement ps = prepare(conn, "SELECT * FROM `marriage_data` WHERE `player_id_1` = ? OR `player_id_2` = ?", id, id)) {
        ResultSet marriageData = ps.executeQuery();
        while (marriageData.next()) {
            int one = marriageData.getInt("player_id_1");
            int two = marriageData.getInt("player_id_2");
            if (one > 0 && two > 0) {
                int spouseId = one != id ? one : two;
                try (PreparedStatement ps2 = prepare(conn, "SELECT * FROM `player_data` WHERE `player_id` = ?", spouseId)) {
                    ResultSet rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();
                    while (rs2.next()) {
                        return rs2.getString("username");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I really need to move away from this messy java+2mysql queries into a single MySQL query. Any guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

```
`player_data` structure
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| player_id       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username        | varchar(32)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |

`marriage_data` structure
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| player_id_1 | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| player_id_2 | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

Sample data from `player_data`
+-----------+-------------+
| player_id |  username   |
|     48616 |  player2    |
+-----------+-------------+
| player_id |  username   |
|     69054 |  player1    |

Sample data from `marriage_data`

+-----+-------------+-------------+
| id  | player_id_1 | player_id_2 |
+-----+-------------+-------------+
| 233 |       48616 |       69054 |
+-----+-------------+-------------+
```

In the provided sample:

Given 48616 it should return player1

Given 69054 it should return player2

Comment: please provide your table structure with some sample data and expected result, i'll give you the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following query. Replace ENTER_YOUR_PLAYERID_HERE with your input player id

```
select m.player_id_1 as 'original_player_name',m.player_id_2 as 'matched_player' ,p.username as 'input_user_name', 
(select username from player_data where player_id=matched_player) as 'matched_player_name' 
from marriage_data m inner join player_data p on p.player_id=m.player_id_1
and m.player_id_1=ENTER_YOUR_PLAYERID_HERE
union
select m.player_id_2 as 'original_player_name',m.player_id_1 as 'matched_player' ,p.username as 'input_user_name', 
(select username from player_data where player_id=matched_player) as 'matched_player_name' 
from marriage_data m inner join player_data p on p.player_id=m.player_id_2
and m.player_id_2=ENTER_YOUR_PLAYERID_HERE
```

Comment: Avoid spaces in field names

Comment: @leonardo_assumpcao - accidentally added space, now its removed. Thanks for message

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code, it looks like you could do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `marriage_data` AS md
  JOIN `player_data` AS pd1 ON pd1.player_id = md_player_id_1 
  JOIN `player_data` AS pd2 ON pd2.player_id = md_player_id_2 
 WHERE `md.player_id_1` = ? OR `md.player_id_2` = ?
```

Basically, join the `marriage_data` to the `player_data` twice, once for Player 1, again for Player 2.  Keep in mind this may need some tweeking.  You really shouldn't do a `SELECT *`, but since you didn't show any table structure I didn't know what columns were there.  Instead of `SELECT *` you should really specify only the columns you need.  Also, you may get ambiguous columns, which would throw an error.

With the new combined `SELECT`, you should be able to simplify your `WHILE` loop into a single loop that grabs everything.